# updating a variable storing URL from another variable using shell using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file `config.properties` containing a variable

```
baseUrl=http://abcde.p123.xyz.abcde.alphabet.com
```

expected value after updating through shell

```
baseUrl=http://anusis.y765.anc.kjshi.alphabet.com
```

I want to update the value of `baseUrl` from the stored as variable `NEW_URL`

`NEW_URL=http://anusis.y765.anc.kjshi.alphabet.com`

I have tried `sed -i "/baseUrl=/ s/=.*/=$NEW_URL/" config.properties` but got error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your variable contains `/`, you need to use a different delimiter in your regexp. For example `|` :

```
sed -i "s|^baseUrl=.*|baseUrl=$NEW_URL|" /tmp/config.properties
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @mivk, i tried with ```,``` but still got error.